# what are the options for restoring kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have Kafka 0.9. 
Today I need restart Kafka-Server. 
But After restart I checked topics and didn't see all topics except standard

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
__consumer_offsets
```

After start in kafka server logs exist this warning:

```
[2018-03-19 13:10:53,199] WARN Found a corrupted index file due to requirement failed: Corrupt index found, index file (/data/kafka/ae-result-from-0/00000000000000000000 index) has non-zero size but the last offset is 0 which is no larger than the base offset 0.}. deleting /data/kafka/ae-result-from-0/00000000000000000000.timeindex, /data/kafka/ae-result-from-0/00000000000000000000.index and rebuilding index... (kafka.log.Log)
```

how to recover topics correctly?

Comment: What backups do you have? How many nodes do you have in your Kafka cluster?

Comment: I didn't backup. One node.